# Survey of results on graph classes with polynomially many maximal cliques

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

A research problem I am working on in computational topology has connections to graph theory, and in particular the number of maximal cliques in graphs.

Therefore I am interested in graph classes with a polynomial number of maximal cliques.

There has clearly been a lot of research done on this, but even after looking for a bit I was surprised not to find the primary results here summarized in a survey article or book chapter.

Is there any resource like this, that gives an overview or list of graph classes that are known to have a polynomial number of maximal cliques, and the asymptotic bounds known for them?